# Exception NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar, jakarta-mail

I have been working on a mailing app which I would like to compress into a .jar file so that a user can double click to run. I am using the javamail API. In eclipse I "added external jar" and added the mail.jar file and I was able to use all the classes inside of mail.jar while developing in eclipse. Now I want to package them into a jar file, so I used the -jar tool in the command line and I specified a manifest file and all my class files, however when I run the jar, I get this exception:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Multipart
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Multipart
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

I know this has something to do with the mail.jar not being in the jar file, and I've tried including the mail.jar file into my application but nothing works. What can I do?

Comment: You may have 'tried' but you haven't succeeded in adding mail.jar to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

How do you run your application? If you're running your application through command line, you should add the required jars separated with semi-colon, into your application's classpath as such :

> java -cp mail.jar;other_jars your-main-class

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything in one jar file so you can double click that one jar file and run the application, you have two main choices:

1. Extract **everything** from the jar files you want to include, merge them with your application, and create a new jar file with the merged contents.  Don't forget that there's files other than .class files that matter.  I'm not an Eclipse expert but I know some of the ways that Eclipse does this will only include the .class files, which won't work.
2. Use a tool such as the ["onejar" tool](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to "nest" jar files inside jar files.

Good luck!